# How to reference a cell in an Excel Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Photo of Sheet]

Hi,

Im having trouble referencing a cell from this datasheet. I want to be able to reference the cell using the team name. Say for example I want to reference the Points For(PF) of the Green Bay Packers on a seperate sheet. I want to be able to type in the name of a team in a cell and reference this cell to get the output of a specific column for that team. I was hoping someone could give me an example excel formula for this. Thanks

Comment: Vlookup, Xlookup, Index/Match will do.

Comment: it might be helpful i guess if you can create a table to a few of your data instead of image to give you the formula

Answer (score 0):

1. your table is not actually an Excel Table
2. as [harun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr) said you can use any of the mentioned functions. For Such a request you could use `= Index( c3:ae31, match("Green Bay Packers", B3:B31, 0), match("PF", Offset(C2:AE2, , IFERROR( MATCH("Penalties", C1:AE1, 0), 0) ), 0) + IFERROR(MATCH("Penalties",C1:AE1,0),0) )`
3. formula is for "Tampa Bay Buccaneers" and "G" (aka 7) in C3

Comment: Yeah, but this approach will fall over if they want to return the Yds for Penalties, for eg. Duplicate column headings are not helping.

Comment: teylyn - I only pointed to the right direction and gave a demo (I think that's the spirit). However, since I also like challenges, I fixed things to work with both headers in rows 1 and 2